# data_utils.is_generator_or_sequence returns always False

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to use a sequence to train a neural net using batches and keras fit_generator. However my sequence is not being recognised as one. At some point of the training_generator.py script it runs the  data_utils.is_generator_or_sequence test and gets False. Weirdly, when I run the test directly on a Sequence object I have the same result:

```
print(data_utils.is_generator_or_sequence(Sequence()))

False
```

I replicated the function source code extracted from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/data_utils.py and when I run it it works ok:

```py
def my_is_generator_or_sequence(x):

    builtin_iterators = (str, list, tuple, dict, set, frozenset)

    if isinstance(x, (ops.Tensor, np.ndarray) + builtin_iterators):

        return False

    return tf_inspect.isgenerator(x) or isinstance(x, Sequence) or is_iterator(x)
```

```
my_is_generator_or_sequence(Sequence())

True
```

Any clues about that?

Comment: Please include a minimal example that completely reproduces the problem, it could be your imports (mixing keras and tf.keras for example).

Answer (score 0):

How do you import `data_utils`? I test it on tf2.0 rc version, and cannot reproduce your result.

```py
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import data_utils
from tensorflow.keras.utils import Sequence

data_utils.is_generator_or_sequence(Sequence())  # return True
```

Comment: You are right. Apparently there are two different classes named Sequence. `from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import data_utils import keras data_utils.is_generator_or_sequence(keras.utils.Sequence()) # return False`

Answer (score 0):

i couldnt replicate your error but i think i know what you got wrong.

when you called the method `data_utils.is_generator_or_sequence` you passed a new Sequence to it but you didnt show where u imported this sequence from. I assume you used a different `Sequence` class (probably `collections.Sequence`) but the data_utils file contains its own `Sequence` class, and uses that class in this method.

try this:

```
print(data_utils.is_generator_or_sequence(data_utils.Sequence()))
```

Comment: You are right! Apparently there are two classes named Sequence. If I import from tensorflow.python.keras.utils.data_utils.Sequence it works but if instead I use keras.utils.Sequence it does not Thank you for your help!